# ActionResult<FileResult> doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 ActionResult<T> to return a file from controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<FileResult> Download()
{
    var someBinaryFile = "somebinaryfilepath";
    return File(new FileStream(firstExe, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, true);
}
```

But it returns incomplete json instead of starting file download:

```
{"fileStream":{"handle":{"value":2676},"canRead":true,"canWrite":false,"safeFileHandle":
{"isInvalid":false,"isClosed":false},"name":"somebinaryfilepath","isAsync":false,"length":952320,"position":0,"canSeek":true,"canTimeout":false
```

Chrome devtools indicates request status as "(failed)" with tooltip "net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

If I change the code so it returns a FileContentResult then status turns to "200 ok" but still json is written instead of file download:

```
{"fileContents": "somebinaryfilecontent","contentType":"application/octet-stream","fileDownloadName":"","lastModified":null,"entityTag":null,"enableRangeProcessing":true}
```

If I change method signature to

```
public FileResult Download()
```

Or to

```
public IActionResult Download()
```

Then file download starts with both FileResult implementations.

How could I use ActionResult<T> to download file? Am I missing something or is it really some kind of bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `ActionResult<T>`, the `T` in this case is the [specific type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#specific-type) you want to return. By default, when returned from an action either directly or using `ActionResult<T>`, this type is serialised as JSON, as you've demonstrated in your question.

For your example, where you're not returning a specific type at all, you'll want to use `IActionResult` (as you've seen, according to your question), like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Download()
{
    ...
}
```

You could also use `ActionResult`, `FileResult` or `FileStreamResult`, but `IActionResult` is preferred.

---

Here's an explanation of *why* I think this is happening in the first place.

`ActionResult<T>` contains two implicit operators:

```
public static implicit operator ActionResult<TValue>(TValue value)
{
    return new ActionResult<TValue>(value);
}

public static implicit operator ActionResult<TValue>(ActionResult result)
{
    return new ActionResult<TValue>(result);
}
```

In your example, when returning a `FileStreamResult`, both of these implicit operators could be used. One operates on *any* type (`TValue`) and the other operates on an `ActionResult`. I expect that the C# compiler is choosing the first version, because `TValue` (`FileResult`) is a *better* match for `FileStreamResult` (your actual return value).

This is covered in the [C# spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) under section "11.5.4 User-defined implicit conversions". Specifically, I think it's this description that applies (I'm no expert here):

> Find the most-specific source type, SX, of the operators in U:
>
> - If S exists and any of the operators in U convert from S, then SX is S.
> - Otherwise, SX is the most-encompassed type in the combined set of source types of the operators in U. If exactly one most-encompassed type cannot be found, then the conversion is ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.

In this case, `FileResult` is the *most specific source-type* (it's more specific than `ActionResult`).